# List without first item selected not being created during binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a list in my model that is created dynamically.

I iterate through this list and create radio buttons for each item in the list.

```
public class Model
{
    public List<string> Options { get; set; }
    public List<string> SelectedValues { get; set; }
}
```

In the view I'm doing this

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.SelectedValues.Count; i++)
{
    <div>
        @foreach (var option in Model.Options)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedValues[i], option) 
        }
    </div>
}
```

(assuming `Model.Options` is populated with something meaningful).

My problem is that if no radio button is selected for the first item in the list (`Model.SelectedValues[0]`) then `SelectedValues` is null when the form posts, regardless of the other selections made.

Is it possible for the list to be created anyway when the model is bound? I don't mind if the first item is null, I just don't want to lose all items when the first is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a hidden input to to specify an indexer for the collection so that non sequential indexes are bound

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.SelectedValues.Count; i++)
{
  <div>
    @foreach (var option in Model.Options)
    {
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedValues[i], option) 
    }
    <input type="hidden" name="SelectedValues.Index value="@i" />
  </div>
}
```

[Refer this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) for a more detailed explanation